# Inputting a file name and having the text read

Tags: c++, fstream, readfile

I want the user to enter the name of a file, and if the file exists, print out all the contents of the file.

At the moment the uncommented code, takes a name of a file that the user inputs, for example.     example.txt and prints out most (not the last word?) of the file. I've tried to implement this instead by using string (commented code is attempt) but clearly its incorrect.

I also wondering if i can automatically add .txt to the end of the user input, so that the console could ask - "which subject should we find more information on" user inputs "math" and it will open "math.txt"

Here is what I´ve tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    char filename[50];
    //string getcontent;
    ifstream name;
    cin.getline(filename, 50);
    name.open(filename);

    if (!name.is_open()) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char word[50];
    name >> word;
    while (name.good()) {
        cout << word << " ";
        name >> word;
    }

    //if (!name.is_open()) {
        //while (! filename).eof())
        //{
            //getline(name, getcontent)
            //cout << getcontent << endl;
        //}

        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //comes from cstdlib
    //}



    //}



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char filename[50]` when you can use `std::string`?

Comment: The same goes for `char word[50]` don't do that. This is C++. Also, `system("pause")` is a bad practice as it is not portable. Use `std::cin.get()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string filename;
    string getcontent;
    ifstream name;
    cin >> filename;
    filename.append(".txt"); // add extension.
    name.open(filename);

    if (!name.is_open()) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        getline(name, getcontent);
        if (name.eof()) break;
        cout << getcontent << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i understand it now. however im not getting the text posted to the console some reason? my file is in the right directory

Comment: You are on Windows, right? I tested this on Linux. Do you mean the console closes immediately so that you cannot see the output? If yes, put `system("pause");` before `return 0`.

Comment: yes im on windows and i did that, when i type "example" and have example.txt in my directory. It says 'press any key to continue' rather than 'this is the text in the file'.    If i  open a file that doesnt exist in my directory the program closes as intended

Comment: Sorry I am not good with Windows when it comes to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it helped me with a somewhat different problem and I also thought that I might be able to help. This is coded in windows. (I'm a beginner so forgive me if I made some obvious mistakes)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin;
int main()
{
    //char filename[50],word[50];
    string filename,word;
    //cin.getline(filename,50);
    getline(cin,filename);
    //strcat(filename,".txt");
    filename.append(".txt");
    fin.open(filename);
    if(fin.is_open())
        while(fin>>word)
            cout<<word<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"No such file"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```